# SQL select rows with unique ID's

Tags: sql

I have two separte tables that have the same columns but some different data:

Table 1

```
ContextID | Property1 | Property2
1         | Hello     | Kitty
2         | Power     | Rangers
3         | Foo       | Bar
```

Table 2

```
ContextID | Property1 | Property2
4         | Scooby    | Doo
2         | Power     | NotRangers
3         | Foo       | NotBar
```

I want to select rows from table 1 where the context ID does not exist in table 2, regardless of the fact that the rest of table 2 might not match table 1. For ex, I want my query to return:

```
ContextID | Property1 | Property2
1         | Hello     | Kitty
```

This is because ContextID `2` and `3` exist in Table 2. How can I write a query that can do this? I was able to write this:

`SELECT ContextID from Table1 EXCEPT SELECT ContextID from Table2;`

However, this only returns the `ContextID` column. How can I grab the entire row (eg. ContextID along with Property1 and Property2?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an anti-join:

```
select a.*
from table_1 a
left join table_2 b on b.ContextID = a.ContextID
where b.ContextID is null
```

Result:

```
contextid  property1  property2 
---------- ---------- --------- 
1          Hello      Kitty
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c36rZE4o2NU9EtTm8xBniQ/0).

Comment: Not sure if that works. Isn't this printing only the rows that have `ContextID = null` ?

Comment: @EfthymiosKalyviotis An anti join works by performing a left join and then discarding all rows with matching values in the rigth table.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is:

```
SELECT t1.ContextID, t1.Property1, t1.Property2
FROM Table1 as t1 
WHERE t1.ContextID NOT IN (SELECT ContextID From Table2);
```

Comment: Beware, this solution won't work if the tables have nulls. Avoid `NOT IN` unless you are sure there are no nulls in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a anti-semijoin, with an "NOT EXISTS" clause in your WHERE.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 from t2 WHERE t1.ContextID = t2.ContextID
)
```

It makes it so any row that matches the `t1.ContextID = t2.ContextID` clause gets omitted, but only the data from t1 is retrieved.